# C# find large prime numbers

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program in C# that will find all the prime numbers up to the max size of UInt64, unless there's a numerical data type larger than UInt64. I've already written the simple program but for some reason, it's returning every single number I check as a prime even if they're not supposed to be a prime number. Here's what I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UInt64 count = 0;
        List<UInt64> primes = new List<UInt64>();
        bool prime = true;

        do
        {
            for (UInt64 i = 2; i < count; i++)
            {
                if ((count % i) == 0)
                {
                    prime = false;
                }
            }

            if (prime == true)
            {
                primes.Add(count);
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }

            count++;
            prime = true;

        } while (count < UInt64.MaxValue);
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my algorithm. Because every time I do the check for a prime, it thinks every number is a prime and will print it out.

Comment: You should consider using a [primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) -- it's much more performant than your algorithm.

Comment: That algorithm supposedly might miss a few prime numbers when you get to very high numbers which I intend to do. I want to make sure I can capture every single prime number possible and the only way to ensure that is to brute force test every single number.

Comment: @Generalkidd I can't see the bug, but you will not get to very high numbers with an n-squared algorithm like this.

Comment: @Generalkidd Are you sure it shows every number is prime. You just think so because you are seeing so much numbers you cannot read just add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` to the last line in the do-while and you will see it works perfectly

Comment: How can I get to higher numbers then? Which numerical data type in C# can hold the largest numbers?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you ever reach the higher primes. As written this will take a long time to run.

Comment: If you need even longer numbers you can use BigInteger from the System.Numerics namespace which was introduced with .NET 4.0.

Here is an article about the usage of BigInteger:http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/01/25/biginteger.aspx?m=1

Answer (score 2):

I literally copy-pasted your code into Visual Studio, ran it and it worked perfectly. The algorithm is sound, although you could definitely optimize it.

Comment: You're right, I set the max value of count to 100 so I could see the first few sets of numbers. I guess when I had the program print out all the primes as it discovered them, the console printed so fast that it looked like all it was doing was printing every single number from 1 to the limit (haven't reached yet).

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, 0 and 1 is not prime and it is a very slow algorithm. You shoould consider some optimaze the code. Like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
But your code should work fine.

Comment: I've been running this program for the past hour or so, I'm not sure where it's at right now because I remove the console output, but in task manager, the program itself doesn't use much CPU power. In fact, it's only using about 28% of my total CPU power. I'm currently running this on my Windows 8 Intel Atom Z2760 tablet. Why isn't the program taking full advantage of all the CPU power available to go faster?

Answer (score 0):

```
    IEnumerable<UInt64> PrimeNumbers(UInt64 maxCap = UInt64.MaxValue)
{
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;

    for (var i = 4; i <= maxCap; i++)
    {
        var isPrime = true;
        for (var j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)
        {
            if (i % j != 0) continue;
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }

        if (isPrime) yield return i;
    }
}
```